# Inserting only part of a string into an SQL databases using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a new C# coder and I am also new with Microsoft SQL Server. The code I have written will parse data from a file using filehelpers and then will place that data in a SQL table. My question is whether it can parse the data but only place part of the string in the SQL server. For example, here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace OnQ_prototype
{
    class Report
    {
        [DelimitedRecord("\t")]
        [IgnoreEmptyLines()]



        public class ColumnReportNames
        {
            public String textbox22;
            public String textbox29;
            public String textbox24;
            public String textbox23;
            public String PSFullAcct;
            public String AccountDescription;
            public String BusDateAmount;
            public String ThisPTDAmount;
            public String LastPTDAmount;
            public String ThisYTDAmount;
            public String LastYTDAmount;
            public String BusDatePctAvail;
            public String ThisPTDPctAvail;
            public String LastPTDPctAvail;
            public String ThisYTDPctAvail;
            public String LastYTDPctAvail;


        }

        static void ProcessFilesCSVFiles(string originalPath, string destinationPath)
        {

            foreach (var GenesisDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(originalPath))
            {
                foreach (var inputFile in Directory.GetFiles(GenesisDirectory, "*.csv"))
                {

                    string lines = inputFile;

                    FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ColumnReportNames));
                    var records = engine.ReadFile(lines) as ColumnReportNames[];
                    foreach (var record in records)
                    {



                        SqlCommand cmd;
                        SqlConnection conn;
                        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hureports01;Initial Catalog=hureports;Integrated Security=True");
                        conn.Open();
                        var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"MERGE [OnQReport] AS target USING (select @Property as Property, @Date_of_Report as Date_of_Report, @Percent_Occupancy_PAR as Percent_Occupancy_PAR, @val as {0}) AS source ON (target.Date_of_Report = source.Date_of_Report) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {0}= source.{0} WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Property, Date_of_Report, Percent_Occupancy_PAR, {0}) VALUES (source.Property, source.Date_of_Report, Percent_Occupancy_PAR, source.{0});", column);
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property", record.textbox24);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_of_Report", record.textbox23);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent_Occupancy_PAR", amount2);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", amount);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();

                    }
```

So one of the values I am adding is Date_of_Report which is located in textbox23. However, the value of textbox23 is Business Date: 6/14/2016. Is there a way for it to only put the date in Date_of_Report (i.e. get rid of "Business Date:"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes it's a simple matter of programming.   Please google "C# string parsing examples" and try the examples you find.   If you encounter an error you don't understand, try posting that as a question.

Comment: Thank you. I am pretty new to coding but this helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] getDate = textBoxVal.Split(':');
string dateOfReport = getDate[1];
```

Are you storing this as a SQL datetime? You may want to convert it afterward.

Relevant fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ql40kl